# htaccess rewrite rule for a part of URL

Tags: .htaccess

I try to change over htaccess from

```
http://www.mydomainname.com/main/something/something
```

to

```
http://www.mydomainname.com/store/something/something
```

I want to replace /main/ to /store/

Can you please help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/main(/.*)?$ /store$1
```

Comment: its works , but sometimes url will be like .... http://www.mydomainname.com/main/  to http://www.mydomainname.com/store/